# How to add a rtf formatting in the text string for a Richt Text Box?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, richtextbox, rtf

In a .NET project I have a long plain text build as concatenation of several strings

```
StringLongText = text1 + text2 + ... + textN
```

each string "textX" is the result of an evaluation. 
At the end of a started process, I show the result in a RichTextBox doing simply:

```
rtfTxt.Text = StringLongText
```

All works fine, but I am not able to add any text formatting in the previous text1, text2, textN blocks.

For example I would like to write some words in bold or italic including the formatting directly in the strings before concatenating them.

Doing

```
text1 = "This is some {\b bold} text"
rtfTxt.Text = text1
```

did not work.

Any suggestion? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
rtfTxt.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi This is some \b bold\b0 text.}";
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the right way.
Anyway I need to write some extra code in order to format the string: for example a CrLf new line must be inserted in the right way in the rtf plain text (i.e. \par) otherwise I get an endless line from my string.
The problem is that the strings are very complex and created by different objects: I should add the rtf tag direclty in the methods of those objects, but I do not like the idea because I prefer to take separate the implementation.
Maybe I should change the design of those objects replacing directly the strings with rtf objects.

Comment: Is there some control to download who can do the job - in case of `code in textbox` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just write required content with formatting to RTF File. Load RTF file in richtextbox. Verify. 
Read RTF content into the textbox. Put textbox content to RTF as:

```
Richtext.rtf = textbox1.text; // (which is textual content)
```